# Flutter iOS Simulator

Tags: flutter

I know this question have been answered but I don't know whats the problem for me.
It it the versions?Should I update OS?  Providing screenshots below. I have also tried with android studio but still.

P.S: I prefer working with VS code

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have XCode 12, you need to update your MacOS version.

Depending on your current computer, it may be possible by going in the System Preferences app, then "Software Update",

Comment: Thank you for answer. There is no update available for my mac. So that means If I update it manually it might be to heavy for my system?

Comment: If you don't have any update available for you system, it might be that you're system is too old for the support of the new version of MacOS :/